# Define the same Grunt Task twice with different properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I use Grunt to run Nightwatch tests. I have created a Grunt task for running an express proxy server that is run before the tests can be run. Then I registered a task to run this proxy first and after that execute the Nightwatch tests. Now I want to register a second Grunt task that runs a different express server and then executes the nightwatch tests. How can I define a second express task? This is my express task:

```
express: {
      options: {
          // Override defaults here
      },
      dev: {
          options: {
              script: 'server/server.js'
          }
      }
  },
```

And I start it like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('testnightwatch', [ 'express:dev' , 'nightwatch']);
```

I need something like this:

```
express2: {
      options: {
          // Override defaults here
      },
      dev: {
          options: {
              script: 'server/server2.js'
          }
      }
  },
grunt.registerTask('testnightwatch', [ 'express2:dev' , 'nightwatch']);
```

But this does not work... Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: exactly which grunt plugin you are using for grunt express?

Comment: i am using [grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
express: {
      options: {
          // Override defaults here
      },
      dev1: {
          options: {
              script: 'server/server.js'
          }
      },
      dev2: {
          options: {
              script: 'server/server2.js'
          }
      }
  },
```

and start it like this

```
grunt.registerTask('testnightwatch1', [ 'express:dev1' , 'nightwatch']);
```

or this

```
grunt.registerTask('testnightwatch2', [ 'express:dev2' , 'nightwatch']);
```

Comment: This is what [grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) suggests. Can you try this again with exact same configurations. Otherwise you might want to raise an issue on their github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like that :

```
express: {
    express1 : {
        options: {},
        dev: {}
    },
    express2 : {
        options: {},
        dev: {}
    }
}
```

But you have to check if your task supports multi task.

Comment: could you please write exactly how i can start one of the express tasks? i don't really get it from the grunt documentation.

Comment: You can try something like that : 

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'express:express1');